# kernel module cannot find firmware file on Android device; where should it be?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, firmware

I am having trouble placing firmware properly on an Android device, I keep getting:

```
<3>[ 3590.997375] usb 3-1.4: ath9k_htc: Firmware - htc_7010.fw not found
```

If on a standard linux machine running Ubuntu, I place htc_7010.fw in /lib/firmware then I do not get this error.

However, if I place this firmware in /lib/firmware on Android, I still get the error.  I have tried all of the following directories and still receive the error:

```
/lib/firmware
/etc/firmware
/system/lib/modules
/system/lib/firmware
/system/etc
```

No such luck... what dictates where the firmware should be, and how could I determine which directories it is scanning for the firmware?

Answer (score 8):

On Android (ICS anyways) it has its own daemon/service (or whatever you want to call it) to manage hotplug events, including firmware requests.   In `<android>/system/core/init/devices.c`, there are two `#define`s that specify locations where firmware will be checked:

```
#define FIRMWARE_DIR1   "/etc/firmware"
#define FIRMWARE_DIR2   "/vendor/firmware"
```

On my initial build of the ICS filesystem, `/etc/firmware` didn't exist (and the etc directory seems to be a symbolic link created at boot/init time).   The directory I had to place firmware in on my NFS mounted rootfs was `<mount point>/system/etc/firmware`

After doing this, request_firmware() calls from my module successfully completed.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with my firmware named : `down3.bin` 
(Beforehand, I had insert my module `"io_ti.ko"` with `# insmod` of course)

When I plugged my device (USB-RS232 converter, *Digi International EdgeportTI1 port adapter*) on my Android tablet (*Samsung Galaxy Tab 2*), he was unable to find his firmware in "linux android adapted directories".
So, like you, I tried to put my `"down3.bin"` in:

```
/lib/firmware
/etc/firmware
/system/lib/modules
/system/lib/firmware
/system/etc
```

with :`# dmesg` I still had error :

> ```
> <6>[00000.00000] io_ti 1-1:1.0 : Edgeport TI 1 port adapter converter detected
> <6>[00000.00000] Failed to load image "edgeport/down3.bin" err-2
> <6>[00000.00000] io_ti:probe of 1-1:1.0 failed with error -5
> ```

```
err -2 = [ENOENT] = No such file or directory.
```

In fact, like you mentionned :

> In `<android>/system/core/init/devices.c`, there are two `#define`s
>   that specify locations where firmware will be checked:
>
> ```
> #define FIRMWARE_DIR1   "/etc/firmware"
> #define FIRMWARE_DIR2   "/vendor/firmware"
> ```

---

**- So you have to put your firmware in one of these directories. It
   worked properly for me, hopefully.**

---

Answer (score 1):

The kernel executes a user-space script to load the firmware.
Check if you have the script on the right location.

1. Check the which location the kernel looks for the script.
   / # cat /proc/sys/kernel/hotplug. The default location is "/sbin/hotplug".
2. Check if you have the script, the kernel is looking for, in this location.
   On android the script should be "/system/busybox/sbin/mdev", so you can set "/proc/sys/kernel/hotplug" to this, if it is not.

Comment: The OP is working on an Android device which does not have udev. Android's init process handles uevents.